# How to ensure Math.acos gets value in range [-1..1]

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

Calculating angle between 2 vectors you must use `Math.acos` (**EDIT**: turns out one does not have to use `Math.acos` since there is `Math.atan2`-way), which accepts only values in range of `[-1..1]`. But if `vector1.x==vector2.x` and `vector1.y==vector2.y` AND due to nature of JS that leads to situations when `0.1+0.2>0.3` sometimes `Math.acos` gets something `>1` and, not surprisingly, returns `NaN`.

I solve it with an if-check before all the calcs and `if (v1.x==v2.x&&v1.y==v2.y)` i just `return 0`
And `if (v1.x==-v2.x&&v1.y==-v2.y) return Math.PI`.

I did it like that (***EDIT*** in accepted answer has a better version):

```
function angle(origin, p1, p2, sign=false){
    if (p1.x==p2.x && p1.y==p2.y) return 0
    if (p1.x==-p2.x && p1.y==-p2.y) return Math.PI
    const a = {x: p1.x-origin.x, y: p1.y-origin.y}
    const b = {x: p2.x-origin.x, y: p2.y-origin.y}
    sign = sign && a.x*b.y < a.y*b.x ? -1 : 1
    return sign * Math.acos(
        (a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y)/(Math.sqrt(a.x**2+a.y**2)*Math.sqrt(b.x**2+b.y**2))
    )
}
```

It works, but if there is a better and more efficient way than do a bunch of mid-complex logic checks at ~60fps if you do some dynamic graphics?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You could just `isNaN(NaN)`. It has nothing to do with the `Math.acos` function, it comes down to trigonometry. The result of the acos function can never be more than 1 or less than -1. Therefore the inverse of the acos function can not take an argument that is more than 1 or less than -1.

Comment: @mplungjan srsly? I do get the question, and don't have an answer, so this is actually a good one.

Comment: But please click edit and snippet editor and show us some code

Comment: *I solve it with an if-check* that sounds fun, could you show us some sample datavthat works with one but not with the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use acos, use [atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) instead. For acos to work, you have to normalize the difference, and handle angle>pi case differently. With atan2, you just supply the difference of the y,x coordinates, and the rest is correctly handled.

**EDIT**

You wanted the angle between the vectors, not the argument of the difference vector, my bad. We just have to change how you handle calculation errors. With some pseudocode:

```
function angle_between(ax, ay, bx, by) {
    var al = ax*ax+ay*ay;
    var bl = bx*bx+by*by;
    var dot = (ax*bx+ay*by)/Math.sqrt(al2*bl2);
    if (dot >= 1) return 0;
    if (dot <= -1) return Math.PI;
    return Math.acos(dot);
}
```

**EDIT2**

Alright, let's see an `atan2` solution too. as @njuffa pointed out, `atan2` can still be used to calculate the angle between two vectors. One less squareroot, which is good. It also gives us a signed angle, which is even better for some applications. It only works in 2D though.

```js
function signed_angle_between(ax, ay, bx, by) {
    var dot = ax*bx + ay*by;
    var cross = ax*by - ay*bx;
    return Math.atan2(cross, dot);
}

console.log(signed_angle_between(3, 4, 30, 40));
console.log(signed_angle_between(2, 5, -50, 20));
console.log(signed_angle_between(2, 5, 50, -20));
console.log(signed_angle_between(1, 1, -1, -1));
```

Comment: Your recommendation of using `atan2` is spot on, this is the most numerically stable method. I don't understand why your example shows use of `acos` given your awareness of the superiority of the `atan2` approach. From memory, the formula based on `atan2` is something like `angle (a, b) = atan2 (a · b, | a × b | )`. I would have to go look up the exact details to be sure.

Comment: Splendid!!! Your **EDIT2** example not just solves the problem, but blows it out of the water!!! ;DDD It's short, efficient, stable, accurate and doesn't need any if-checks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The computation based on `acos` does not only have a problem with spurious NaN triggered by rounding errors causing its argument to exceed unity, it also has numerical issues for results near 0 and near π, causing results to be inaccurate.

A superior approach which avoids both issues is based on `atan2`: angle (a, b) = atan2 (| a × b |, a · b). I do not know Javascript, but would expect the following ISO-C code implementing this to translate pretty much one-to-one to Javascript:

```c
double angle (double ax, double ay, double bx, double by)
{
    double dot = ax * bx + ay * by;
    double norm_cross = fabs (ax * by - ay * bx);
    return atan2 (norm_cross, dot);
}
```

In my experience, the computation using `atan2` should have roughly the same performance as the computation via`acos`, but of course if will depend on the specifics of the math library used.

Comment: Thank you!! That's in deed more accurate and right way! What is `fabs`, is it `absolute` value? Is it necessary?

Comment: @Stas Shepelev `fabs` is the absolute value, correct. With this, my function will be semantically equivalent to the `acos` variant you seem to be using now: results are in [0,  π]. Without it, you will get a signed angle, which may or may not be what you want. I figured the conservative approach is to give you exactly the same functionality as you were already using, *minus* the problems with accuracy and arguments out of bound.

Comment: I see=) Actually I had to do some extra calcs to get the sign. I didn't mention it because it does not affect the [-1..1] bounds problem with acos, and I didn't want to clutter the question with unnecessary details.